# Doesn't post-order traversal require subtrees to be evaluated separately?

Tags: data-structures, binary-trees, search-algorithms, trees, search-trees

Consider this tree:

[image: Simple binary tree]

If I traverse it using post-order, I'd start at *B* (as it is the leftmost leaf) and that's where my misunderstanding begins. I know *B* is the first and *A* will be the last node in post order, as the rule is left-right-root. One of my university professors said the correct answer for the post-order traversal of a tree similar to the one above would be ***B*, *C*, *D*, *E*, *A***, but in my understanding, it should be ***B*, *D*, *E*, *C*, *A***.

Am I getting it wrong? Shouldn't I evaluate *(C,D),(C,E)* as a subtree and then go back to the parent tree?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right. You finish each sub-tree before printing that sub-tree's root node. The correct order is B, D, E, C, A